# BAQ for Configuration Data

Tags: epicorerp

We have a requirement to query data from each configuration.  Although I can access this data from Opportunity/Quote Tracker-->Configuration, I can't seem to query this.  Which table should I query?

Answer (score 0):

The data for the Product Configurator is stored in the Erp.PcInValue table.

This is an EAV (Entity, Attribute, Value) table and has one value stored in each row.

Comment: When I query the table (with no filters) I get no results, even though we have configured opportunity/quotes.  Do you know why that might be?

Comment: Update: see item in answerbook below:
Page:       18210MPS

    PcValueSet cannot be queried with BAQ at this time. The way we store the data in XML formats prevent it from being able to be used in BAQ at this time.